# Proof of $(\bigcup\limits_{i\in I} A_{i})\bigcap B =\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}(A_{i}\bigcap B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A_{i}(i\in I$), $B$ are subsets of $X$ 
>  Prove that:
>   $(\bigcup\limits_{i\in I} A_{i})\bigcap B =\bigcup\limits_{i\in
>  I}(A_{i}\bigcap B)$

I was trying to prove it by using the method of mathematical induction.
For i=1 the equation looks like

$(\bigcup\ A_{1})\bigcap B =\bigcup\ (A_{1}\bigcap B)= A_{1}\bigcap B$

Now need to prove equation for I=n+1, considering that it is true for I=n

$(\bigcup\limits_{i\in I=n+1} A_{i})\bigcap B =((\bigcup\limits_{i\in I=n} A_{i})\bigcap B) \bigcup(A_{n+1} \bigcap B) $  using distribution law

$((\bigcup\limits_{i\in I=n} A_{i})\bigcap B) \bigcup(A_{n+1} \bigcap B) = (\bigcup\limits_{i\in I=n}(A_{i}\bigcap B))\bigcup(A_{n+1} \bigcap B) = \bigcup\limits_{i\in I=n+1}(A_{i}\bigcap B)$

Is everything ok in this proof?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this proof doesn't quite work; you can't use induction on $I$, because $I$ may have infinite size (whereas induction would only work for $I$ having finite cardinality).

Rather than using induction, note that every element in the RHS is in $B$ and also in some $A_i$, and hence is an element of the LHS. Similarly, any element in the LHS must be in $B$ and in the union of all $A_i$, the latter of which means that it's in some $A_i$, and hence is an element of the RHS.

So both sides are subsets of each other, and so they're equal.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is not O.K, since $I$ is an arbitrary set (an index-set).

1. Let $x \in (\bigcup\limits_{i\in I} A_{i})\cap B$, then there is $i_0 \in I$ such that $x \in A_{i_0} \cap B$ This gives $x \in \bigcup\limits_{i\in
    I}(A_{i}\cap B).$ Thus we have shown that

$$(\bigcup\limits_{i\in I} A_{i})\cap B \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i\in
 I}(A_{i}\cap B).$$

2. It is now your turn to show that

$$(\bigcup\limits_{i\in I} A_{i})\cap B \supseteq \bigcup\limits_{i\in
 I}(A_{i}\cap B).$$